# Normal Subgroups with factor groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

In part ii) I understand $(Nx)^2=Nx^2=N $ $(Nx \text{ order }2)$   but I do not understand why this implies $x^2\in N$

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $g \in G$, then $g \in H $ iff $Hg=H$.

$g \in H \Rightarrow Hg=H$

> Since $H$ is closed under multiplication $Hg \subseteq H$. On the other hand, if $h \in H$, then we can write $h= hg^{-1}g$ and $hg^{-1} \in H$ since $g \in H$ and $H$ is closed under taking inverses (it is a subgroup!). Hence $h \in Hg$.

$g \in H \Leftarrow Hg=H$

> Since $1 \in H$, $1.g \in Hg=H$, so $g \in H$.

Comment: How can i prove this?

Comment: Will put it in my answer with spoilers. You should try it yourself too!